# angular shopping cart getTotal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm using angular and am looping through an array of food. i set each ng-model to a different model (food.zero, food.one, food.two) and my controller looks like this:

```
     $scope.food = [
        {
            "name": "Tomato Soup",
            "price": 5,
            "quantity": ''
        }, {
            "name": "Garden Salad",
            "price": 5,
            "quantity": ''
        }, {
            "name": "Dinner Plate",
            "price": 12,
            "quantity": ''
        }

    ];
     $scope.addToCart = function() {
        $scope.food.quantity = $scope.food.zero;
        $scope.food[1].quantity = $scope.food.one;
        $scope.food[2].quantity = $scope.food.two;

    };

    $scope.getTotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.food.length; i++) {
            var yum = $scope.food[i];
            total += (yum.price * yum.quantity);
        }
        return total;
    };
```

the partial:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="food.zero"
                       type="number"
                       class="form-control bfh-number"
                       placeholder="Quantity"
                       ng-minlength="1"
                       ng-maxlength="2"
                       style ="width: 100px"
                        />
              </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addToCart(food)">Add To Cart</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">

        <a onclick="return false;" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Salad</h4>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body"style="max-height:400px">
          <img style="float:left" height=50% width=50% src="http://9ad4fbf943e652b35b9f-c4a49d76d48cd1b152556e6b92003f52.r98.cf2.rackcdn.com/i/food/dishes/large/tomato-basil-bisque-536.png">
          <div style="float:left">Vine-ripened pear tomatoes pureed with fresh cream for a velvety smooth flavor accented by hints of red pepper and oregano and topped with our homemade asiago cheese croutons. Served daily.<br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="food.one"
                       type="number"
                       class="form-control bfh-number"
                       placeholder="Quantity"
                       ng-minlength="1"
                       ng-maxlength="2"
                       style ="width: 100px"
                        />
          </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addToCart(food)">Add To Cart</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">

        <a onclick="return false;" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
               <h4 class="panel-title"> Entrée</h4>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body"style="max-height:400px">
            <img style="float:left" height=50% width=50% src="http://9ad4fbf943e652b35b9f-c4a49d76d48cd1b152556e6b92003f52.r98.cf2.rackcdn.com/i/food/dishes/large/tomato-basil-bisque-536.png">
            <div style="float:left">Vine-ripened pear tomatoes pureed with fresh cream for a velvety smooth flavor accented by hints of red pepper and oregano and topped with our homemade asiago cheese croutons. Served daily. <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="food.two"
                       type="number"
                       class="form-control bfh-number"
                       placeholder="Quantity"
                       ng-minlength="1"
                       ng-maxlength="2"
                       style ="width: 100px"
                        />
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addToCart(food)">Add To Cart</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div align="left" id="cart"><h2>Your Cart</h2>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="f in food">
            <td>{{f.name}}: {{f.price | currency}} x {{f.quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div align="center" style="width:200px;">
    <h2>Total: {{ getTotal() | currency }}</h2>
```

what happens is the total starts as $0.00, then when i add something it disappears and when i finally have the 3 quantities fulfilled it shows the total price. i know this is ugly, horrible, vile code and i feel guilty about it. but i haven't been able to get it to work. i just want to understand! why does is disappear/reappear with the right price?

Answer (score 0):

in getTotal check that f is not undefined before using it.
also this block looks like a hack that might cause issues

```
if (total == null) {
                total = ''
            }
```

remove it. if there is an issue after removing it, fix the code not to add bad food items.

Comment: i changed 'f' to 'yum' and now the second and third items can be added together in total, but the first can't be added in at all.

Comment: can you post the code? some things don't make sense like in html you put arg to addToCart but in function you ignore it and set it hardcoded. than you say if you add just 1 or 2, but the function adds/sets to 3 every time hardcoded. so what you are doing and the code you gave just don't match.

Comment: the first item still can't be added...and no items appear unless i pass food as an argument in the template

Comment: ok, now i see it. you have several issues. 1) quantity is a string instead of a number. if no quantity than put 0. it messes up your multiplication later on. 2) if food holds all selected foods, why does it have a field quantity? if its an array, don't put fields to it. 3) if food is an array, but you got $scope.food.zero and $scope.food.two and all that? basically it all boils down that you are messing up that field called food as if it holds all the data that you can think of. you need to split things up. its not related to angular at all.